# Find the crontab file and rename it

Tags: bash, cron

When editing the crontab, find it named a very strange name

```
"/tmp/crontab.hyJx4E" 2L, 95C
```

However, it cannot be found in the /tmp file

```
[root@iz2ze9wve43n2nyuvmsfx5z ~]# ls /tmp
Aegis-<Guid(5A2C30A2-A87D-490A-9281-6765EDAD7CBA)>
hsperfdata_root
systemd-private-048fd2d0909c4a159b248529f71e0aa7-mariadb.service-v0PKHW
systemd-private-048fd2d0909c4a159b248529f71e0aa7-nginx.service-7M7eMY
systemd-private-048fd2d0909c4a159b248529f71e0aa7-ntpd.service-rI4iwH
```

How could I find the crontab file and rename it?

Comment: It's just a temporary file generated by Linux to let you edit it and Linux will persistent content of the file when you exit from vim. So you couldn't find it. You can tell me why you want to rename it.

Comment: If you rename it, it will no longer work. Why do you want to rename it? If you want a copy, grab the contents of the file and create a new one with the contents you just copied.